# How to create Google Static Map with polyline data

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-api-nodejs-client, google-maps-static-api

How can we create a google static map with a custom polyline overlay?

I need to create a map image, which has to be embedded into a pdf report. The basemap will be google, and on top of that, we need to show the markers and polylines.

I could see some docs to include marker while creating google static maps. but couldn't figure out a solution for including custom polyline on that. I've the polyline data in my database as geojson and can change it to any other defined format if required, from a nodejs api.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: If you checked out their official [doc](https://developers.devsite.corp.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#Paths), you would see how to add custom paths.

Comment: @RickyCuarez - that url resolves to a google SSO login page. Try [this url instead](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#Paths)